# Alternate bold and regular text in phpWord footer

Tags: php, phpword

I can alternate plain and bold text in the body of a document using `textrun` within a `section`.

```
$textrun->addText(' Short address here ');
$textrun->addText(' T ', $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' ++353 1 5552999. ');
```

But I can't get the same effect where I need it, in the FOOTER. Text is added with `$footer->addText` which doesn't allow inline additions of new text.

I've tried everything I know, including concatenating and assigning `$textrun->addText` outputs to a new `$variable`, which I add just once to the footer via `$footer->addText($variable)`; No luck.

My current code is as follows, and I'd be really grateful if someone could tweak it to work.  Or is it just that footers in phpWord don't support this level of formatting?

```
// footer
$footer = $section->addFooter();

// define bold style
$boldFontStyleName = 'BoldText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldFontStyleName, array('bold' => true));

// add text
$footer->addText(' Short address here ');
$footer->addText(' T ', $boldFontStyleName);
$footer->addText(' ++353 1 5552999. ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use textrun similarly in footer as you would in section (at least in phpword version 0.13.0):

```
// footer
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();

// define bold style
$boldFontStyleName = 'BoldText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldFontStyleName, array('bold' => true));

// add text
$textrun->addText(' Short address here ');
$textrun->addText(' T ', $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' ++353 1 5552999. ');
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I'd tried that, but I must have left something out. That's twice you've saved me!